# Add a cross-fade to a ProRes clip

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, prores

I have a ProRes 422 HQ trailer clip that is about 70 seconds. I would like to add a 0.5s cross fade (to black/silence) at the head and tail of the clip. The output file must have the exact same characteristics as the input file.

Where I'm starting at is something like (in ffmpeg):

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:??|trailer.mov|??" -c copy output.mov
```

Is there a way to do this with ProRes 422 in ffmpeg. If not, what other tools might work for this kind of thing? Note: all the video files are on a linux server, so it's something I'd need to do via a command-line and not something like Final Cut.

Is this possible to do in Compressor via command line, or what might be the best starting place to try and do this?

Comment: Will the fade-in/out add to the duration of the clip or take effect on the first and last 0.5 seconds of the existing clip?

Comment: @Gyan It wouldn't add to the duration.

Comment: Then the easiest way is to use the fade filter and re-encode the video.

Comment: @Gyan on what -- ffmpeg you mean?